# expected 'void (**)(void *, const char *)' but argument is of type 'void (*)(void *, const char *)

Tags: c, function-pointers, libxml2

I can't figure out what

```
void (**)(void *, const char *)
/*    ^^ why are there 2 asterisks here?
```

means, it's a pointer to a function but I fail to

The exact error message is

```
expected 'void (**)(void *, const char *)' but argument is of type 'void (*)(void *, const char *)'      
       initGenericErrorDefaultFunc (xmlGenericErrorFunc *handler);      
       ^
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlerror.h:866:
```

this is the default error message function in `libxml2`, the function that I am trying to call is

```c
initGenericErrorDefaultFunc (xmlGenericErrorFunc *handler);
```

and my `handler` argument function is

```c
void
skipErrorPrinting(void *ctx, const char *msg, ...)
{
}
```

then I call `initGenericErrorDefaultFunc()` like this

```c
initGenericErrorDefaultFunc(skipErrorPrinting);
```

and here the definition of `xmlGenericErrorFunc`

```c
typedef void (XMLCDECL *xmlGenericErrorFunc) (void *ctx,
                 const char *msg,
                 ...) LIBXML_ATTR_FORMAT(2,3);
```

Comment: How do you call `initGenericErrorDefaultFunc` ?

Comment: The obvious way `initGenericErrorDefaultFunc(skipErrorPrinting);`.

Comment: Two stars means it's a pointer to a pointer to a function.

Comment: @quantdev I did, it din't work, in fact the same error message was generated. I think passing the function name is the same as passing it's address.

Comment: OR (if possible) redefine skipErrorPrinting:

Comment: lesson from this: -1 for using pointer typedefs, -2 for using pointer typedefs that don't even have "P" or "Ptr" or similar in the typedef name

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes someone should tell the `libxml2` developers. Looking at `initGenericErrorDefaultFunc (xmlGenericErrorFunc *handler);` I feel a little stupid for not noticing the `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty wonky, it wants to *return* the default error handler.  So you have to pass a pointer to a variable.  Like this (untested):

```
xmlGenericErrorFunc handler;
initGenericErrorDefaultFunc(&handler);
```

If I understand your intentions properly, this is not the function you actually want to use to suppress errors.  Use xmlSetGenericErrorFunc() instead.  You can use initGenericErrorDefaultFunc() to restore it again.  Pass NULL.

Comment: This was it, wow! I cant believe it... I thought of using two `&` but of course for that a I need this trick, an it makes sense after looking at `initGenericErrorDefaultFunc (xmlGenericErrorFunc *handler);` carefuly. I have to parse some really buggy `html` so I need to silence libxml2.

Answer (score 0):

You use `xmlGenericErrorFunc *handler`. Note the asterisk. `xmlGenericErrorFunc` is already typedefined with one. Simply remove the asterisk after `xmlGenericErrorFunc`, it is already a pointer.

Comment: Apparently `initGenericErrorDefaultFunc` is a third party library function with this signature, so it'd be preferable to figure out what the function is expecting, rather than to go and change the function.

Comment: Maybe it initializes the function pointer and expects pointer to a location where it can store it? Hard to tell without documentation.